# Represent BitWise AND,OR,SHIFT Operations in PseuodoCode

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How Can I represent bitwise AND, OR Operations and Shift Operations using PsuedoCode?

Please Hep me

Answer (score 1):

You said bitwise, so why not `&` (AND) `|` (OR) and `<<` (left shift) or `>>` (right shift)?

Fairly universal C-style syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent **implementations** of bitwise operations, you can introduce "bit enumerator" (some kind of object to iterate over that will emit bits from the less significant one to the most significant for given number) and use mapping for arguments to result (like AND and OR definition suggests).